# Postgresql user_function with string inputs

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a simple postgres user_func to look up and return FIPS codes given a state code and a county name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fips(state_code varchar, county_name varchar) RETURNS varchar AS $$
SELECT concat(statefp, countyfp) FROM fips
    WHERE state = state_code AND county LIKE county_name+'%';
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

In the `fips` table, the `county` column sometimes has extra stuff after the county name (like `Maricopa County` or `Maricopa Cty`). I will be passing in just `Maricopa` so I need to use a `LIKE` I assume.

I've tried the `AND county LIKE county_name+'%';` several ways but keep getting syntax errors. Is there a way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres the concatenation operator is `||` (not `+`), so:

```
    WHERE state = state_code AND county LIKE county_name || '%';
```